# Divide polygon into parts of certain size?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a shapefile polygon which is 13 acres. I want to divide it for 3, 4 and 6 acres polygons.

Is there any plugin or something which I can divide the original polygon?

I use Qgis 2.18.5
[image]

I added a photo how I want to divide

Comment: Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the Polygon Splitter plugin? You can find it marked as experimental in versions 2.18.x.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach by hand and some Python code (for using in the QGIS Python console).

1. Create the `Oriented minimum bounding box` for the acre layer (search for it in the Processing Toolbox) and save the temporary layer to a shape file like `measure.shp`. In my case the acre layer is called `acre`. Then you can move the new feature with the `Move Feature tool` until you think the overlap could be the area of interest you want.

   [image]
2. Then open your QGIS Python console and paste following code in it:

   ```
   acre_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('acre')[0]
   measure_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('measure')[0]

   for a in acre_lyr.getFeatures():
       for b in measure_lyr.getFeatures():
           if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
               intersection = a.geometry().intersection(b.geometry())
               print intersection.area()
   ```

   The output should be something like this (in my case):

   ```
   644.867112592
   ```
3. If I want a new polygon (field) with an area of 600m² I have to move the measure feature a little bit to the north. Afterwards I paste my Python code one more time and check the output (=area). I do this until I approximately have an area of 600m². If I want to be very accurate I have to zoom several steps in and move the feature in very small steps.
4. Then you can clip the acre layer with the measure layer to get the new polygon with 600m².
5. To get a next new part (say 200m²) from the acre polygon you have to calculate the difference between the clip and acre layer first (temporary Layer is called "Difference"). If you have save the outputs to a temporary layer you have to change the value `'acre'` to `'Difference'`in the the Python code.

   [image]

   Green is the Difference and red the Clip.
6. Do steps 1-3 with the Difference layer without using a new bounding box ...